# Obtaining "virtual key" code to remap a shortcut of my choice to the £ symbol on a US keyboard layout

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, powertoys

Although I live in the UK, due to circumstances beyond my control, I am now using a US keyboard, and have therefore set the keyboard layout to US in Windows 11.

I don't want to faff around with the shortcut of "ALT key and type the number 0163" to obtain the £ symbol. Instead I just want to use something like Right Alt + 4 to obtain it. Microsoft Powertoys allows you to remap keys. However, it doesn't seem to allow a £ symbol in the "Mapped to" section.

[image: Powertoys GUI]

I'm therefore wondering if I can use a "virtual key" code instead which might produce the £ symbol. How would I determine this code number? I found [this link](https://cherrytree.at/misc/vk.htm), but no luck with any pound symbol. Or maybe there's something better and more logically designed than PowerToys that gives a much more diverse set of characters?

Comment: AHK should be much easier to set up for such tasks.

Comment: @Destroy666 I'll try that as a last resort, but I can't believe there isn't a util designed for such basic functionality.

Comment: @Destroy666 - AHK did the trick easier than expected. Posted an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found that using the free AutoHotkey v2 along with this script did the trick:

```
!4::£      ; Alt+4 prints £
!`::¬      ; Alt+` prints ¬
!\::¦      ; Alt+\ prints ¦
>!4::€     ; AltGr+4 prints €
```

[Key Manager](https://atnsoft.com/keymanager/) from ATNSoft also worked, but costs $60 (though does support a bunch of other stuff too, such as recording key/mouse sequences and playing them back at will).